# Element becomes invisible when parent div is positioned as relative and child div as absolute

Tags: html, css

I have a form wizard and I want to implement some transition when the change step buttons are clicked. I created a `div` and set its `position: relative` and `overflow:hidden` and now I added 2 divs inside and pushed it to the left. The second div I positioned as absolute. But now this div became invisible. I want this div to be visible and the hidden overflow on parent element. Any ideas how to solve the problem?

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eXU74/)

Some **CSS:**

```
.registration {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}
.registration .registration-box {
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    position: relative;
}
.registration [class*="registration-base-block"] {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: left .6s;
    -moz-transition: left .6s;
    -ms-transition: left .6s;
    -o-transition: left .6s;
    transition: left .6s;
}
.registration .registration-base-block1.hidden-forever {
    left: -980px;
}
```

Some **HTML:**

```
<div class="registration">
    <div class="registration-box">
        <div class="registration-title">
            <div class="registration-step1">Step 1</div>
            <div class="registration-step2 disabled">Step 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="registration-base-block1 hidden-forever">
            <div class="registration-inside-block">
                <label for="txt">Textfield here: </label>           
                <div class="registration-input">
                    <input name="txt" id="txt" type="text" maxlength="30" value="asdf"/>                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="registration-base-block2">
            <div class="registration-inside-block">
                <label for="txt2">Another field:</label>            
                <div class="registration-input">
                    <input name="txt2" id="txt2" type="text"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update (for those who did not understand the question):**

I have added the hidden overflow to the parent `div` because I am going to apply transition in the inside div and change its left property, so if I will not add `overflow:hidden`, when I would animate the form that is inside, I would see the form overflowing parent element.

Comment: try to set some min-height for parent div

Comment: @Kiran it shows exactly that amount which I have set to the parent div

Comment: That's impossible. `overflow:hidden` has no exception.

Comment: i didn't understand what you are trying to do here? you only set overflow hidden. after that you wnat to display content. Only one way is keep the new div position fixed. so it will be visible all the time.

Comment: @rhgb there should be a way, nothing is impossible.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I want the parent div to know the height of the inside div, I want to make the parent div flexible.

Comment: so why you want overflow:hidden??

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I don't want to see a form outside of a parent div while I am transitioning.

Comment: fix some height and mention overflow:auto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved question using javascript. When the page is loaded the function sums the height of a title `div` and the height of an inside `div` and applies it to the parent `div`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".registration-box").height($(".registration-title").height() + $(".registration-base-block2").not(".hidden-forever").height());
});
```